# Does merge sort essentially trade space for time when compared to insertion sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, insertion-sort

I am trying to understand, kinda intuitively, how the runtime for merge sort is so much better than insertion sort.

Even though we divide and conquer with merge sort, on a single CPU, each of the nodes of the merge sort execution tree will be executed serially. *Is the smaller input size on every recursive call (iteration) somehow the key thing for merge sort?*

*Or is it the fact that since merge sort is not in-place and uses O(n) space this saves on the number of shifts we have to do in insertion sort to make space for the insertion of the smaller number.*
But what about the penalty of copying the elements in left and right temporary arrays in every merge step?

Comment: Create a *comparison sort* using O(1) additional time with a run time *dominated* by n² and get famous.

Comment: > penalty of copying - efficient merge sorts avoid the copying by changing the direction of merge as needed. I explained this in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that smaller input size is in large part where the speed up of mergesort comes from compared with insertion sort. The fact that mergesort uses more space is more an artifact of how it works than an inherent reason for the speedup.

Here’s one way to see this. We know that insertion sort, on average, takes time Θ(n<sup>2</sup>). Now, suppose you want to insertion sort an array of n elements. Instead, you cut the array apart into two smaller arrays of size roughly n/2 and insertion sort each of those. How long will this take? Since insertion sort has quadratic runtime, the cost of insertion sorting each half will be roughly one quarter the cost of insertion sorting the whole array ((n/2)<sup>2</sup> = n<sup>2</sup> / 4). Since there are two of those arrays, the total cost of sorting things this way will be roughly

> 2(n<sup>2</sup> / 4) = n<sup>2</sup> / 2,

which is half the time required to sort the original array. This gives rise to a simple sorting algorithm that’s an improvement over insertion sort:

- Split the array in half.
- Insertion sort each half.
- Merge the two halves together.

That last step introduces linear space overhead for the merge, though you could do it with an in-place merge at a higher cost.

This algorithm, “split sort,” is about twice as a fast as insertion sort. So then you might ask - why split in halves? Why not quarters? After all, the cost of sorting one quarter of the array is about

> (n/4)<sup>2</sup> = n<sup>2</sup> / 16,

which is sixteen times faster than sorting the original array! We could turn that into a sorting algorithm like this:

- Split the array into quarters.
- Insertion sort each quarter.
- Merge the quarters into halves.
- Merge the halves into the full array.

This will be about four times faster than insertion sort (each sort takes one sixteenth the time of the original sort, and we do four of them).

You can think of mergesort as the “limit” of this process where we never stop splitting and divide the array into the smallest units possible and then merge them all back together at the end. The speedup is based on the fact that sorting smaller arrays is inherently faster than sorting larger arrays, with the memory overhead for the merge being more of an implementation detail than an intrinsic reason for the speedup.

Another way to see that the space usage isn’t necessary for the speedup is to compare insertion sort to heapsort. Heapsort also runs in time O(n log n) but uses only O(1) auxiliary space.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. This helps in getting a feel for how the speedup is achieved.

Comment: This also helped me understand why divide and conquer works. It's easier / faster to solve smaller problems as long as merging the solution is not cost prohibitive.

Comment: @Reep - the smaller input size is not the reason that merge sort is faster than insertion sort. The reason merge sort is faster is due to it's time complexity of O(n log(n)) versus insertion sort's time complexity of O(n^2). It's just a better sorting algorithm for n > ~128.  If sorting integers, radix sort is faster still with O(n) time complexity, and the separation of data is based on the values of the elements, not the number of elements, and it operates on much larger input sizes than merge sort, and it is significantly faster.

Comment: @Reep - Splitting until the smallest units possible is not faster. Once unit size is around 32 to 64 elements, it's faster to switch to insertion sort, or simpler still, start off using insertion sort to create sorted runs of 32 to 64 elements, then merge runs, which is a hybrid of insertion sort and bottom up merge sort. This how most libraries implement stable sort.

Comment: @rcgldr You’re correct that it’s faster at some point to have mergesort switch to insertion sort to finish processing each “block.” But I’d argue that the reason why mergesort is faster is indeed due to reducing the size of the problem until it becomes manageable. The O(n log n) runtime is a consequence of this strategy.

Comment: @templatetypedef - but radix sort is faster still and doesn't reduce the size of the problem down as much as merge sort. If sorting 2^28 = 268,435,456 integers base 256, it reduces size to ~1048576 integers in each of 256 bins (for near uniform distributed data), while merge sort would reduce size to 1 element or if a hybrid insertion sort + merge sort to 32 or 64 elements. Merge sort reduced the size of the problem much more than radix sort, but radix sort is faster.

Comment: I’d argue that in some sense radix sort is reducing the problem size. Rather than sorting n numbers that are d digits each, radix sort iteratively sorts n numbers that are one digit each. That does reduce the problem size, though in a way that’s different than what merge sort does. The main speedup of radix sort, though, is the ability to place things in sorted order directly by their numeric value rather than using comparisons.

Comment: @templatetypedef - "by value" rather than "comparison", which is my point, it's not the smaller size, but just that some algorithms for sorting are better than others. On a side note, top down merge sort is mostly used for learning purposes. Most libraries use some hybrid insertion sort + bottom up merge sort. Bottom up merge sort is still divide and conquer, but the division is done in one step at the beginning, rather than pushing/popping n pairs of index to/from the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Even an in place merge sort (O(1) space) is faster than insertion sort for n >= ~128 on a typical X86.

For smaller n, insertion sort is faster, due to cache and related constant factors, and because of this, most library implementations of stable sort use a hybrid of insertion sort (to create small sorted runs) and bottom up merge sort.

An example of an in place merge sort is block merge sort (grail), O(1) space, still with O(n log(n)) time complexity, but about 50% slower than a standard merge sort, and the code is complicated:

https://github.com/Mrrl/GrailSort/blob/master/GrailSort.h

> But what about the penalty of copying the elements in left and right temporary arrays in every merge step?

Typical merge sort avoids copying of data by doing a one time allocation of a temporary array and then changes the direction of merge based on merge pass for bottom up merge sort, or level of recursion for top down merge sort.